# Equality Function Generator

Tags: c#

I have a small open source library called **Equ** that I've been using already on several projects. After a rework of the internals I thought I'd ask here for opinions on improvement possibilities.

At the core of my library is a class that generates equality functions, i.e. `bool Equals<T>(T a, T b)` and `int GetHashCode<T>(T obj)`.

It takes a type and a set of `MemberInfo` objects that define which members (properties or fields) should be included in the equality functions. The class generates a `Func` as output for each of `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` using expression trees. The idea behind this approach is that the slow reflection code needs to be run only once per type, using the resulting lambdas as sort of a cache for the code.

Here's the code of the central class of the library, `EqualityFunctionGenerator`. This is a copy of [this](https://github.com/thedmi/Equ/blob/b53e67859940b76750cc77d37d02f3e7a8e817bd/Sources/Equ/EqualityFunctionGenerator.cs).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public class EqualityFunctionGenerator
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _objectEqualsMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    private readonly Type _type;

    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable<FieldInfo>> _fieldSelector;

    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> _propertySelector;

    public EqualityFunctionGenerator(Type type, Func<Type, IEnumerable<FieldInfo>> fieldSelector, Func<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> propertySelector)
    {
        _type = type;
        _fieldSelector = fieldSelector;
        _propertySelector = propertySelector;
    }

    public Func<object, int> MakeGetHashCodeMethod()
    {
        var objRaw = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "obj");

        // cast to the concrete type
        var objParam = Expression.Convert(objRaw, _type);

        // compound XOR expression
        var getHashCodeExprs = GetIncludedMembers(_type).Select(p => MakeGetHashCodeExpression(p.Item1, p.Item2, objParam));
        var xorChainExpr = getHashCodeExprs.Aggregate((Expression)Expression.Constant(29), LinkHashCodeExpression);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, int>>(xorChainExpr, objRaw).Compile();
    }

    public Func<object, object, bool> MakeEqualsMethod()
    {
        var leftRaw = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "left");
        var rightRaw = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "right");

        // cast to the concrete type
        var leftParam = Expression.Convert(leftRaw, _type);
        var rightParam = Expression.Convert(rightRaw, _type);

        // compound AND expression using short-circuit evaluation
        var equalsExprs = GetIncludedMembers(_type).Select(p => MakeEqualsExpression(p.Item1, p.Item2, leftParam, rightParam));
        var andChainExpr = equalsExprs.Aggregate((Expression)Expression.Constant(true), Expression.AndAlso);

        // call Object.Equals if second parameter doesn't match type
        var objectEqualsExpr = Expression.Equal(leftRaw, rightRaw);
        var useTypedEqualsExpression = Expression.Condition(
            Expression.TypeIs(rightRaw, _type),
            andChainExpr,
            objectEqualsExpr);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object, bool>>(useTypedEqualsExpression, leftRaw, rightRaw).Compile();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Tuple<MemberInfo, Type>> GetIncludedMembers(Type type)
    {
        var selectedFields = _fieldSelector(type).Select(f => Tuple.Create((MemberInfo)f, f.FieldType));
        var selectedProperties = _propertySelector(type).Select(f => Tuple.Create((MemberInfo)f, f.PropertyType));

        return selectedFields.Concat(selectedProperties);
    }

    private static Expression LinkHashCodeExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        var leftMultiplied = Expression.Multiply(left, Expression.Constant(486187739));
        return Expression.ExclusiveOr(leftMultiplied, right);
    }

    private static Expression MakeEqualsExpression(MemberInfo member, Type memberType, Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        var leftMemberExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(left, member);
        var rightMemberExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(right, member);

        if (memberType.IsValueType)
        {
            return MakeValueTypeEqualExpression(leftMemberExpr, rightMemberExpr);
        }
        if (IsSequenceType(memberType))
        {
            return MakeSequenceTypeEqualExpression(leftMemberExpr, rightMemberExpr, memberType);
        }
        return MakeReferenceTypeEqualExpression(leftMemberExpr, rightMemberExpr);
    }

    private static Expression MakeValueTypeEqualExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        return Expression.Equal(left, right);
    }

    private static Expression MakeSequenceTypeEqualExpression(Expression left, Expression right, Type enumerableType)
    {
        return MakeCallOnSequenceEqualityComparerExpression("Equals", enumerableType, left, right);
    }

    private static Expression MakeReferenceTypeEqualExpression(Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        return Expression.Call(_objectEqualsMethod, left, right);
    }

    private static Expression MakeGetHashCodeExpression(MemberInfo member, Type memberType, UnaryExpression obj)
    {
        var memberAccessExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(obj, member);
        var memberAccessAsObjExpr = Expression.Convert(memberAccessExpr, typeof(object));

        var getHashCodeExpr = IsSequenceType(memberType)
            ? MakeCallOnSequenceEqualityComparerExpression("GetHashCode", memberType, memberAccessExpr)
            : Expression.Call(memberAccessAsObjExpr, "GetHashCode", Type.EmptyTypes);

        return Expression.Condition(
            Expression.ReferenceEqual(Expression.Constant(null), memberAccessAsObjExpr), // If member is null
            Expression.Constant(0), // Return 0
            getHashCodeExpr); // Return the actual getHashCode call
    }

    private static Expression MakeCallOnSequenceEqualityComparerExpression(string methodName, Type enumerableType, params Expression[] parameterExpressions)
    {
        var comparerType = typeof(ElementwiseSequenceEqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(enumerableType);
        var comparerInstance = comparerType.GetProperty("Default", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null);
        var comparerExpr = Expression.Constant(comparerInstance);

        return Expression.Call(comparerExpr, methodName, Type.EmptyTypes, parameterExpressions);
    }

    private static bool IsSequenceType(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type != typeof(string);
    }
}
```

The referenced `ElementwiseSequenceEqualityComparer` is basically just a wrapper around `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`. It can be found [here](https://github.com/thedmi/Equ/blob/b53e67859940b76750cc77d37d02f3e7a8e817bd/Sources/Equ/ElementwiseSequenceEqualityComparer.cs).

I'm especially interested in opportunities to further improve performance and simplicity. And, of course, if you see any problem with my approach or implementation, that would be great to know as well.

### Edit: Usage Details

The primary use case of **Equ** is with value objects, where usually all members participate in the equality comparison. This use case is covered by [MemberwiseEquatable](https://github.com/thedmi/Equ/blob/master/Sources/Equ/MemberwiseEquatable.cs) and makes it very simple for clients, because all fields are captured, even when the value object class is changed later.

Under the hood, `MemberwiseEquatable` uses the `EqualityFunctionGenerator` shown above. Clients can also use the `EqualityFunctionGenerator` directly when they need more control over the exact members that participate in equality comparison.

See also the short introduction [here](https://github.com/thedmi/Equ).

Comment: Have you considered supporting `IComparable<T>` too?

Comment: @svick I thought about that as well, but I think that's conceptually not as easy as it might seem at first sight. With equality, it is simple - two value objects are equal when all their parts are equal. But what should a `a.CompareTo(b)` method return, when `a.Part1 > b.Part1` and `a.Part2 < b.Part2`?

Comment: With `IComparable`, order matters: you compare the objects by `Part1` first and only if they're equal, you look at `Part2` (in other words, you're basically doing `.OrderBy(x => x.Part1).ThenBy(x => x.Part2)`). Because of this, I think it makes sense to support only explicit member lists for this (no “compare by all fields”).

Comment: @svick Exactly, and as a result, the main "selling point" of my library (i.e. not having to explicitly list members, see https://github.com/thedmi/Equ#simple-scenarios) would be defeated. But I agree that this would be a useful addition! Pull requests welcome, btw :-)

Comment: If my understanding is correct (and it really could not be :P) you compare each member and properties of your object to test the equality?

Comment: @TopinFrassi Yes I do! This is the correct way to implement value object equality in my opinion, see https://github.com/thedmi/Equ#compositional-integrity for an explanation. But please state your point of view if you think differently.

Comment: What do you mean when you describe Equ as "convention-based"?

Comment: @BenAaronson The fact that you don't have to list every single member that should participate in equality comparison, as you would have to when you'd implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` yourself. This manifests as the `MemberwiseEqualityComparer<T>.ByProperties` and `MemberwiseEqualityComparer<T>.ByFields` conventions, with more customization available when required (through `MemberwiseEqualityComparer<T>.Create()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add XML comments, especially for important items (like `EqualityFunctionGenerator`) and potentially confusing items (like `fieldSelector`).

---

```
typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

Safer way to do this would be to create a delegate for `object.Equals()` and then take its [`Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method):

```
new Func<object, object, bool>(object.Equals).Method
```

---

```
equalsExprs.Aggregate((Expression)Expression.Constant(true), Expression.AndAlso)
```

You don't need to use `seed` here, this will work too:

```
equalsExprs.Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso)
```

---

```
var objectEqualsExpr = Expression.Equal(leftRaw, rightRaw);
```

This won't work if the type also overloads `==` by delegating to `Equals()` (which is the most reasonable implementation). Instead, I think you should just return `false` when the types don't match.

---

```
Expression.TypeIs(rightRaw, _type)
```

This doesn't actually check whether the type of `rightRaw` is `_type`, it checks whether it's `_type` *or a type derived from `_type`* (just like `is` does in C#). Here, I think you want to know whether the type is exactly `_type`. You can do this by calling `GetType()` (and don't forget to add a `null` check before doing that).

---

```
private static Expression MakeEqualsExpression(MemberInfo member, Type memberType, Expression left, Expression right)
```

You don't need the `memberType` parameter here, you can use `leftMemberExpr.Type` instead.

This means you can get rid of the `Tuple` in `GetIncludedMembers()` and return just the `MemberInfo`.

---

```
private static Expression MakeGetHashCodeExpression(MemberInfo member, Type memberType, UnaryExpression obj)
```

I don't see any reason why `obj` should be a `UnaryExpression`, you should use `Expression` here.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your inputs! I didn't know the Method member of Func and that Expression has a Type property.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you shouldn't compare all members and properties. Lets say your object has an ID property that defines the identity of your object, you might not want to compare all your fields/properties knowing that comparing only one is enough. Or if you are using an ORM and that not all your navigation properties are loaded, your objects wouldn't be equal even though they "are".

As a solution, I think you could put attributes to the properties/fields that define the equality of your object, something like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    [EqualityMember]
    public int PropertyThatWillBeCompared{get;set;}

    public int PropertyThatWontBeCompared{get;set;}

    [EqualityMember]
    public int PropertyThatWillAlsoBeCompared{get;set;}
}
```

Then you could scan your `PropertyInfo` and `MemberInfo` for those who have this attribute and compare them. (Obviously, this solution will only work with your objects, since you have the source)

Comment: I think that's what the `fieldSelector` and `propertySelector` parameters are for.

Comment: Maybe indeed, it isn't very clear. Though I asked the OP if he was comparing all the properties/fields in the question's comment and he said yes... If your point appears to be true I'll just remove my answer!

Comment: Maybe I should have explained the intended usage scenarios better. I did so now, see the updated question. Svick is right, `fieldSelector` and `propertySelector` serve the purpose of specifying which members participate in the equality comparison. However, your suggestion with attributes would be a clearer way for the clients. That way, I would be able to hide the complexity of the `EqualityFunctionGenerator` even for the more advanced cases.

Comment: I use this approach for my equality class and it works like a charm ;)